# Why is fnDeleteRow is resetting current page in jQuery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using **fnDeleteRow** to remove a specific row in a jQuery datatable. The problem is that if the user is in a different page than 1, after the row is removed, the user is back at page 1, altough he/she removed the item in another page, e.g.: 4.

```
var datatable_test = $("#datatable_test").dataTable({
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [-1],
        "bSortable": false,
        "bSearchable": false,
        "mRender": function(data){
            return "<a href="#" class="action_delete" id="delete_" + data + "">delete</span>";
        }
    }],
    "bProcessing": true
});
$(".action_delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.post("helper.php", { action: "delete", id: id }).done(function(){
        $(row).fadeOut("fast", function(){
            datatable_test.fnDeleteRow(datatable_test.fnGetPosition(row));
        });
    });
});
```

The user should remain in page 4 after the item is removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself if somebody is interested:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings ) {
    return {
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage": Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
        "iTotalPages": Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
}
```

And then:

```
var page_number = datatable_test.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
datatable_test.fnDeleteRow(datatable_test.fnGetPosition(row), function(){datatable_test.fnPageChange(page_number);}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
 datatable_test.fnDeleteRow(datatable_test.fnGetPosition(row));
```

**With**

```
var DataTable_Test= $("#datatable_test").DataTable();
DataTable_Test.row(row).remove().draw( false );
```